# How to write a cross platform setup script in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, installation, cross-platform, hbase

I am new to ruby and just beginning to understand It's potential. So I am trying to use it for my everyday tasks. One of those things would be the setup of a Webservice on a local machine for testing. It set up script should:

- check out several projects from subversion repositories
- install Hadoop (if it's not already installed), start the Server and execute a few commands in the hbase shell
- install the JDK (if not installed)
- install MySQL (if not installed) and execute some SQL to create and set up the DB
- Install maven (if not installed) and run some maven tasks.

So here's the deal. I want this to be a cross platform installer - it should be able to install the Webservice on Windows, Linux or OsX.

Is it possible to implement this in Ruby and what gems could be useful for that task? Are there better ways to create such an installation routine?

Regards

R.

Comment: Are the installation processes similar across platforms?

Comment: Basically yes - I need to perform the same steps and run the same commands on mysql,mvn and hbase. But the installation process for the JDK, Maven, Hadoop and MySQL is of cause different on other platform. I don't necessarily need do include this in the installation process, but it would be a nice feature.

Comment: For the similar process - look at [rake](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake). For the differences - well it's the same problem as in any script (or documentation) - detect which environment it is, and then run the relevant code...

Comment: I was hoping that there are some platform independent gems to run maven, hbase and so on.

Comment: I suspect that you won't find much maven support in ruby, since it is a java tool...

Comment: So would I be better of writing classic shell and batch scripts?

Comment: I don't think I have enough information to give you an authoritative response, and anyway that would only be my opinion - do what you feel better serves your task and your goals, I believe you can do it both ways and in other ways... can't maven itself contain installer tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Chef](http://www.getchef.com/). It provides an automation framework for managing systems. It's written in Ruby and you use a mostly Ruby [recipe DSL](http://docs.getchef.com/dsl_recipe.html).

People package [Cookbooks](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_cookbooks.html) for managing groups of installation and configuration recipes, which are normally based around a piece of software.

- [Hadoop](https://github.com/continuuity/hadoop_cookbook)
- [MySQL](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql)
- [Maven](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/maven)
- [Java](https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java)

You *will* run into issues bridging the gap between Windows and Unix. Although Chef does provide good Windows support these days most Chef/community cookbooks will support Linux primarily as they can rely on the underlying package manager which Windows lacks. Often you may end up finding/using separate Windows cookbooks specifically for the Windows install.

For when you do need to do a Windows install, look at using [Chocolatey](https://www.gittip.com/Chocolatey/) and it's [cookbook](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-cookbook) which provides a unix like package interface for Windows so you don't need to worry about packaging up the software manually or dealing with random NSIS/MSI installer options.

If you do extend one of the Unix cookbooks to support Windows, be nice and contribute it back to the community.